# Override Angular local-specific time formatting

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, localization, internationalization

I'm using Angular `8.3.28`'s localization service to support English, Spanish (Mexico) `es-MX`, and Spanish (Spain) `es-SP`

When using the `date` pipe:

```
{{ foo.Date | date: 'shortDate' }}
```

dates get changed to the correct locale no problem, but it seems like Angular uses 24 hour time for Spanish regardless of region.

Spanish (Mexico) needs to be in 12 hour, but Spanish (Spain) needs to be in 24 hour.

How can I override the default time format for Spanish (Mexico)?

I'm trying to avoid having to write a custom `date` pipe.

Answer (score 1):

The correct approach will use your custom date pipe. However, if want to avoid the easier is with a ngIf that help you to check if is Mexico or Spain to put the correct date pipe for each case.
Using the default Angular pipe reference UPPERCASE HH.mm instead of hh.mm

```
<div *ngIf='iSMexico'>{{ foo.Date | date: 'shortDate' }}</div>
<div *ngIf='iSSpain'>{{ foo.Date | date: 'largeDate' }}</div>
<div> {{ today | date : 'hh.mm' }}</div>
// 06.00
<div>{{ today | date : 'HH.mm' }}</div>
// 18.00
```

Comment: I see, this is a pretty mature product that needs localization implemented, that's why I was trying to avoid a custom date pipe. I'll also need to support several more locales in the future so I was trying to also void a lot of conditional logic in the templates. I appreciate the response though